# Disable saving autofill information in browser, but allow the user to use it

Tags: html, browser

The goal is to not allow the browser to save any information for autofill, but to still use it if they have the information available.

**For example:** User stored CC info when they made a purchase on another site, I would like to use this to fill out the CC info on the form, but I do not want to the browser to save anything to for autofill for future use.